# Text content in flexbox child causes it to cover its neighbour

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Say I want to have 2 `div` laid out side by side using flexbox. The first one is given a fixed width and the 2nd one fills the remaining width.

```css
.parent {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }

      .child1 {
        background: red;
        width: 300px;
      }

      .child2 {
        background: blue;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2"></div>
    </div>
```

Works perfectly!

Now if I try to add text to the 2nd `div`.

```css
      .parent {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }

      .child1 {
        background: red;
        width: 300px;
      }

      .child2 {
        background: blue;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2">
        aute dolor duis tempor labore amet ut proident elit adipisicing
        incididunt magna enim mollit aute cupidatat adipisicing nulla laborum
        est nostrud consequat in velit est exercitation esse nulla duis quis id
        est aliqua nostrud laborum magna culpa eiusmod sunt aliqua ex dolore
        laborum
      </div>
    </div>
```

Why does the 2nd `div` cover up the 1st `div`? Shouldn't it respect the fixed width I have given the 1st `div` and just wrap its text?

Comment: Nope, not unless you tell it not to shrink. It's a flex child now and width is treated as the *initial* state. Try `flex: 0 0 400px;` instead of width

Comment: use flex:1 for the second div